# Why XRA A also clears other registers too?

Tags: assembly, 8085

Let us suppose accumulator contains 0AH and following instructons are given.
MOV D,A;
XRA A;
I found out that this instruction clears accumulator as well as the D register. 
I confirmed this by using 'Virtual 8085' simulator.
Why the secon instruction clears the D register as well?

Comment: Sorry, it makes no sense. `MOV D, A` would set `D` to `0AH`. Then `XRA A` would set `A` to zero and the net effect would be `D=0AH, A=0`.

Comment: Virtual 8085 appears to be buggy. If you `MOV` `A` into one or more other register(s) and then perform a bitwise logic (and, or, xor) operation on `A` you end up modifying those other registers as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I looked at [Virtual 8085's source code](https://github.com/bhorkarg/virtual8085/tree/master/v8085), and it does indeed look buggy as I suggested in my comment.

It represents registers as `BitArray` instances. Or rather, each register is represented as an object with a `bits` member which is a reference to a `BitArray`.

Now, what the author does to simulate `MOV` is to [simply point one register's `bits` to another register's `bits`](https://github.com/bhorkarg/virtual8085/blob/master/v8085/Virtual8085.vb#L520). Let's say that you do `MOV D,A`; after that `MOV`, `D.bits` is now referring to the same `BitArray` as `A.bits`.
If you then perform a bitwise logic operation you're operating directly on `A.bits`, which will also affect `D.bits` since they refer to the same `BitArray`. The bug doesn't happen if you do e.g. an `ADD` or `SUB`, because they are implemented in a different way and create a brand new `BitArray` instead of modifying an existing one.

It seems to me that `MOV` is implemented in a broken way and should use `Clone`, or possibly `CopyTo` instead of just `=`. File a bug about this on github if you want to see it fixed.

---

TL;DR: `XRA A` does not clear `D`. Virtual 8085 is buggy. Try to contact its author to have him fix the bug, or search for a different simulator.